# Finite temperature quantum mechanics and mixed states

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, thermal-field-theory

Is it necessarily true that a quantum-mechanical system in thermal equilibrium is in a mixed state? If so, why is this the case? Is there any physical intuition as to why one cannot use a pure state description?

I've been told statements such as *"thermal fluctuations in the system make it impossible to obtain a complete (and hence pure state) description of it"*, and *"a many-body system in equilibrium necessarily exhibits decoherence and hence cannot be described by a pure state"*. However, I'm unsure whether these are correct, and if they are, how to interpret them intuitively.

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using a pure state description would imply that you know exactly which microstate the system is in, which usually isn't the case in thermodynamics.

Comment: @probably_someone Is there some physical intuition as to why this is the case? Is it always true that a quantum many-body system in thermal equilibrium will be in a mixed state?

Comment: For what it’s worth this is true even in classical thermodynamics. If you know the temperature and volume of an ideal gas, there is a ton you _don’t_ know. Being able to proceed without this detailed microscopic information is the whole point of thermodynamics.

Comment: One way of interpreting a mixed state is that there is a classical, as well as a quantum uncertainty. This is exactly what you would expect for a thermal state described by statistical mechanics.

Comment: @BySymmetry    Why is it necessarily the case that a thermal state has classical uncertainty though? Where is the information loss?

Comment: That you don't know everything about the system is a key assumption that is necessary for the calculations and variables in thermodynamics to work. The statements that you've been told are essentially *post facto* justifications of this assumption, and there is really no fundamental reason that they should hold (although they generally do).

Comment: @PeterShor     In classical statistical mechanics this is because the system is large enough that in practice it is not possible to obtain complete knowledge of its state, right?! Does an analogous train of thought apply for the quantum case?

Comment: In general, you won't know the system's exact state, but if you did, this fact would not miraculously keep the laws of thermodynamics from working.